# Build up a matrix similar to a given one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Construct a matrix $B \in M(3,\mathbb R)$ such that:

- $B$ is similar to $A = \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & -1 & -1  \\
      1 & 2 & 1  \\
      -1 & -1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \in M(3,\mathbb R)$
- $(1, 0, 1) \in \ker B$
- $\operatorname{Im} B =\{(x,y,z) \in\mathbb R^3 : x-y-2z=0 \}$

How to proceed?

What I did:

Let be $A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & d & g  \\
    b & e & h  \\
    c & f & i \\
  \end{bmatrix}$

For the 2nd condition: $\begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
   a+g=0\\b+h=0 \\ c+i=0
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$

And for the 3rd one: $\begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
   a-b-2c=0\\ d-e-2f=0
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}$

Is it correct? How i can use the first condition?

Comment: First identify $\ker A$, $\mathop{\rm im} A$ and then try to find a change of basis wich transforms these vector spaces to your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood: when I find basis for ker $A$ and Im $A$, these are a base $S$ of $M(3, R)$. Now I have to write another base $S'$ of $M(3, R)$ from the given conditions of B. Is B the matrix of transformation from $S$ to $S'$?

Comment: You bases for the kernel and image will form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$, not $\mathbb R^{3\times3}$. Now if $k$ is a basis vector for the kernel and $i_1, i_2$ form a basis of the image, you seek a map wich maps $k$ to $(1,0,1)$ and $(i_1,i_2)$ to a basis of your plane from point 3.

Comment: Yep sorry i meant $R^3$. I'm trying many times but it seems i'm not arriving to the solution. May you be so kind to write down these last steps?

Comment: You get 9 equations, 3 each for
$$Pk = (1,0,1)^T, Pi_1 = b_1, Pi_2 = b_2$$

Comment: And then $B = P^{-1} A P$